# Background-image css media query no funciona

Tags: css

Estoy intentando cambiar la imagen de fondo para pantallas más pequeñas pero parece que, aunque si funciona en los navegadores del pc si redimensiono, en dispositivos móviles no llega a funcionar.
Os pongo aquí debajo el css que estoy utilizando por si vosotros sois capaces de ver alguna errata.

```
body {
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;  
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url("assets/images/iconos/fondo3.PNG");
}
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
 body {
     background-image: url("assets/images/mobile/fondomobile.jpg");
 }
}
```

En la parte de la etiqueta  del html tengo

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
```

He usado más veces @media en otras partes del .css y funciona perfecto.
Lo dicho, si en el navegador redimensiono y bajo de 576px funciona perfectamente. ¿Por qué en móvil no?

EDIT.
Para que funcione perfecto en todos los navegadores, al final lo he hecho así.

```
body {
  background: url("assets/images/iconos/fondo3.PNG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  body {        
    background: url("assets/images/mobile/fondomobile.jpg");
  }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, la url funciona bien, no es problema de eso.

Comment: https://docentesdecentes.com/ esa es la web por si quieres echarle un ojo

Comment: Lo estaba revisando, en pc funciona perfecto y en móviles también. No logro ver el error que mencionas. La imagen "grande" es ancha con puntos más gruesos, mientras la móvil es más angosta, y con un diseño de puntos mas finos.

Comment: Gracias por las molestias. Si lo miro desde el ordenador funciona bien pero desde los moviles que he probado no funciona. He probado en safari en iphone y no se ve y en chrome en ipad y tampoco sale la versión de puntos mas finos

Comment: Qué raro, igual es algo de ios solo...

Comment: Los móviles guardan demasiado caché para las imágenes, limpia el historial del navegador e intenta de nuevo, asegurate de haber actualizado en línea tu css primero.

Comment: Hola @puluku. En realidad todo está bien. El problema más bien está en la caché y eso lo puedes resolver agregando al final del archivo CSS un signo de interrogación seguido de cualquier cosa. Por ejemplo, si tu archivo CSS es `style.css` lo puedes cambiar por `style.css?v1`. No tiene por qué ser exactamente `v1`. Puede ser cualquier cosa que indique al navegador que está apuntando a otro archivo, aunque en la práctica sea el mismo. Esto es para evitar la caché.

Comment: Gracias David, tenías toda la razón.